# How to sort out an Array with Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I can get my RSS feed printed out to the console in an array form. Every news-item I get is an element of the array. From every news-item is a title, description, link and pub-date available.

I want to get this sorted out wherefore all the titles are being put into an array and all the descriptions are being put into an array and so on.

Is there a way how to do this in Swift?

Here is my data that I want to get sorted out and put into four different arrays:

```
 {
    description = "Voleco-arbiter gelauwerd voor 25 jaar op de bok\n      ";
    link = "https://api.nevobo.nl/permalink/nieuws/18914\n      ";
    pubDate = "Wed, 13 Nov 2019 12:00:00 +0100\n    \n    ";
    title = "Zilver voor Erik-Jan Geneugelijk\n      ";
}
{
    description = "Het einde van het jaar is weer in zicht. Dit houdt in dat er in iedere regio een regiosymposium wordt georganiseerd. Mis het niet!\n      ";
    link = "https://api.nevobo.nl/permalink/nieuws/18913\n      ";
    pubDate = "Tue, 12 Nov 2019 13:54:00 +0100\n    \n  \n";
    title = "Regiosymposia 2019: 'Superclubs'!\n      ";
}
```

Comment: You want to have an array of `description`, an array of `link`, an array of `pubDate` and an array of `title`. Am I right?

Comment: `let descriptions = yourArrayList.map { $0.description }` etc.

Comment: why would you want to seperate them? You should create a struct and store them in array of struct to avoid mismatching of data

Comment: How can I use a struct and store them in array of struct? Can you give same code?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is not sorting, sorting means to set the order of the array following a certain logic.

You just want to create new arrays, you can do it like this

```
let titles = newsItems.map { $0.title }
```

Repeat for different properties and you’ll have the arrays you want.

Comment: some sort of information also much appreciated here regards to use *high order functions* like used `map`.

Comment: I have tried your code suggestion in y project. The result is th e following error: "Value of type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character') has no member 'title'".